# How to set environment variables on remote linux host in a visual studio crossplatform cmake project

Tags: linux, cmake, visual-studio-2017, cross-platform

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to edit a cmake project according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/cmake-linux-project) tutorial

However, my environment is of 64bit, and I need to build a 32bit program. And yes I have all the i386 dev libs on my machine.
I can achieve this on linux simply by typing `CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32" cmake .`. But I just cannot find how to specify remote environment variables in vs' `CMakeSettings.json` or any other way.

I have tried exporting environment variables on linux .profile, but this won't work on vs. Running the same command directly on ssh works fine.
Also have tried setting `cmakeExecutable` variable in `CMakeSettings.json` with prefixed `CC=...`, and got rejected by vs.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not familiar with cmake, it seems just set `cmakeCommandArgs` would work.

In `CMakeSettings.json`, `"cmakeCommandArgs": "-D CMAKE_C_FLAGS=\"-m32\" -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=\"-m32\""`